# what is best scenario of solving long running service in android service is getting shutdown after couple of hours

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation

Business scenario:

The objective of business scenario is to update our longitude and latitude to server for an interval of  every 15 mins in background

I have used Alaram Manger (Restarting Service when service gets shut down by android os)

i have shared my code below :

```
public class GoogleClientFusedApiService extends Service implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationService";

    private boolean currentlyProcessingLocation = false;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    public static Boolean isRunning = false;
    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 15 minutes


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!isRunning) {
                startTracking();
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, 1000 * 60 * 2);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // if we are currently trying to get a location and the alarm manager has called this again,
        // no need to start processing a new location.
        if (!currentlyProcessingLocation) {
            currentlyProcessingLocation = true;
            //startTracking();
            mHandlerTask.run();
        }
        //alarm.setAlarm(this);
        return START_STICKY;
        // return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void startTracking() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startTracking");

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            if (!googleApiClient.isConnected() || !googleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                googleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "unable to connect to google play services.");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {

            String latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            String longtitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            LocationUpdateServerCall locationUpdateServerCall = new LocationUpdateServerCall(getApplicationContext());
            locationUpdateServerCall.pushLocationUpdateServerCall(latitude, longtitude);
            Log.e(TAG, "position: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude() + " accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());

            // we have our desired accuracy of 500 meters so lets quit this service,
            // onDestroy will be called and stop our location uodates
          /*  if (location.getAccuracy() < 10.0f) {
               stopLocationUpdates();
            }*/
        }
    }

    private void stopLocationUpdates() {
        if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandlerTask);
    }

    /**
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
     * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
     * request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES); // milliseconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES); // the fastest rate in milliseconds at which your app can handle location updates
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10); // distance travelled

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        } else {
            return;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");

        startTracking();

      /*  stopLocationUpdates();
        stopSelf();*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.e(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");

        startTracking();
    }

    //Start Alarm(Start Location Updates on Background)
    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
        restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        myAlarmService.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1000 * 60 * 1
                , restartPendingIntent);
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    // Canacel Alarm (Stop Location Update)
    public void cancelAlarm(Activity context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, GoogleClientFusedApiService.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
```

Advance Thanks 
 Waiting For Valuable Guidelines

Comment: You should state the problem you are encountering.

Comment: @jww Hi , after a couples hours automatically my service shuting down please help me out with your valuable guidelines

Comment: How did you manage this ?